# After pasting how to jump to other end of inserted text

Tags: vim

After pasting some text in vim, how can I jump to the other end of the inserted text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `` `[ `` to jump to the first character of the previously changed (or yanked) text.

You can use `` `] `` to jump to the last character of the previously changed (or yanked) text.

This works for me for whether pasting ("putting") from the unnamed register or the system clipboard.

Answer (score 4):

You may like these commands as well `gp` and `gP`. They are like `p` and `P` but leave the cursor just after the new text.